# tkinter listbox selected style to transparent

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have a tkinter `Listbox` containing dynamic int valuesfor example `[1,2,3,4,5]`. I have adapted my code to make it simpler.

```
self.edt_shots = ttk.Listbox(
    self,
    height=7,
    exportselection=False,
    selectforeground="purple",
    activestyle=UNDERLINE,
    #selectbackground="white",  # TRANSPARENT needed here?
)
self.edt_shots.grid(row=3, column=3, rowspan=5)
```

I do some conditional formatting on the background of each item.
So for example all even values would be red and all odd values would be green.

The listbox colors would be `[red,green, red, green, red]`. That works well.

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i, name in enumerate(lst):
   self.edt_shots.insert(i, str(name))
   # conditional formatting
   self.edt_shots.itemconfig(
    i,
    bg="green"
    if i%2 == 1
    else "red"
  )
self.edt_shots.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.on_edt_shots_change)
```

But I am also selecting items. I want to notice when I select items by setting the foreground to purple.

Still good.

But that also changes the background to Blue so it overwrites the background from my conditional formatting which I don't want.

```
def on_edt_shots_change(self, event):
    """handle item selected event"""
    if len(self.edt_shots.curselection()) <= 0:
        return
    index = self.edt_shots.curselection()[0] + 1

    self.edt_shots.select_clear(0, "end")
    self.edt_shots.selection_set(index)
    self.edt_shots.see(index)
    self.edt_shots.activate(index)
    self.edt_shots.selection_anchor(index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `selectbackground` as well when setting the `bg` in the for loop:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i, name in enumerate(lst):
   self.edt_shots.insert(i, str(name))
   # conditional formatting
   bg = "green" if i%2 == 1 else "red"
   self.edt_shots.itemconfig(i, bg=bg, selectbackground=bg)
```